# Zend url rewrite BASE_URL/en to BASE_URL?lang=en

Tags: .htaccess, zend-route, zend-router

I have already spent many hours on this and I think I could use some help.
So I have a local zend project available at http://MY_URL.lh.

I have this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|wfs|csv)$ index.php
```

And I want to rewrite this :

```
htttp://MY_URL.lh/en
```

into this:

```
htttp://MY_URL.lh/?lang=en
```

I have tryed already to add *my rule*

```
RewriteRule /^([a-z]{2})$ /?lang=$1 [R]
```

before the

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

but then no further zend routing works except if I add the flag [C] to *my rule* but the desired behaviour still missing.

Also I have tried with [R=301] flag.

I would appreciate to know why is so difficult to make htaccess rewrite rules in Zend Projects.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule before the other rules i.e. just after the `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ /?lang=$1 [R=301,L]
```

When you added it right before `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]`, this rule, which says stop processing all requests, gets executed all the time, which is why nothing works after.

Edit:

If you do not want to change the address in the URL, which is what the redirect will do, then I presume that you want to continue processing rules after this too, so that the php application will be able to pick up the lang param.  In this case, leave the rule where it is but remove both flags and add the `QSA` flag in case there are other query string parameters present.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ /?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked but it changed the address from the URL bar of the browser, is there a way to do that without changing it ?

Comment: I did that, and the URL address is still changing in the URL address bar.